# How to prevent postback while redirecting to a new page with LinkButton/ImageButton

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ts" ImageUrl="ts.png" runat="server" CssClass="thumbnail" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="Client_Click" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="Lb4" runat="server" OnClick="Client_Click" CssClass="linkOff" Text="E"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Client_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int k = this.Master.Client.ID;
    if (k > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://mypage.com" + this.Master.client.SelectedValue , "_blank", "menubar=0,scrollbars=1,width=780,height=900,top=10,left=0");
    }
    else
        Response.Redirect("http://mypage.edu" + this.Master.client.SelectedValue , "_blank", "menubar=0,scrollbars=1,width=780,height=900,top=10,left=0");
}
```

When I click on either the image button or the link button, the new page opens and the clicked page does a postback.

How can I avoid the postback and just open the new page.

I tried the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Lb4.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return false;");
}
```

When I click the button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in javascript or set `OnClientClick` property , explained here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx.

Or just use `PostBackUrl` property. There are lot of options or simple remove server control use html a-href only. for image button- use `<img>` and wrap with `<a>`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, I am using a value from a ASP.net control in the parameter

Comment: Ok, then use simple javascript to fetch the selected value and build redirect url and then redirect.

Comment: I am getting the value from a master page and the link is in the content page.

Comment: Yes, that you can do with javascript, if you are not familiar with this, then you have go with postback option.

Comment: I need what the link is doing, except the opposite effect.

Comment: Yes, as I told that is doable, just check the viewsource of required aspx page and get exact ID of `Master.client.SelectedValue` and use that id in redirect url , when image/link button is clicked redirect to required link, this way you will achieve what it does plus you will prevent unecessary postback.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to postback, I would recommend just using HTML for your button then. 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_image

The other option is using the button's onclientclick method. If you don't define an OnClick it probably won't postback. (I think anyway)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, I am using a value from a ASP.net control in the parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the postback, you have to move that if-else logic to the client (JavaScript). As for the Master.Client.ID property, one approach is to expose the value in the markup, for example in a `<input type="hidden">` that you can then use in the JavaScript.